# Using Postman to perform Azure AD auth for Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-functions

**Problem:** I'm trying to use Postman to get an valid Azure AD access token that I can then use to pass on a request to an Azure Function protected by Azure Active Directory (Easy Auth).

I've read / viewed numerous explanations on how to do this. CGillum's entire blog for example. Some of the best ones (that don't quite work for me) are:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devkeydet/2016/03/22/using-postman-with-azure-ad/
- https://youtu.be/ujzrq8Fg9Gc
- Even a similar question that I posted: [Authentication for Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757665/authentication-for-azure-functions)

I've verified that my ClientID, secret, and callback are all correct. I've ensured I have (what I think are) the correct permissions to the app I registered in my directory. I've got back a valid Bearer tokens in both of the first two examples above. No matter what though, when I pass this token back in the Authorization header I get a message that states "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

My hope at this point is that someone reading this will point out the obvious thing that I missed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the resource URI you use when you get the access token? For example, if I wanted a token to access Azure AD Graph API, I would use the `https://graph.windows.net` resource URI. This should match what is configured for the app in AAD.

Comment: Great question! I was using https://<myfunctionapp>.azurewebsites.net

Comment: That is probably wrong. You can find the app by finding the Azure Active Directory blade in Azure portal -> App Registrations

Comment: Hmm is the resource URI you're talking about the same as the "App ID URI"? Because that's a madeup bogus thing that it automatically generated when I registered the app.

Comment: Yes that one! It's an identifier for the app :)

Comment: Ok I tried that thingy for the Auth URL and Postman hangs lol. It looks like this:
`https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3A%2F%2F<App_ID_URI_Thingy>%2F`

Maybe I'm supposed to change that thing? Hmm...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160401/discussion-between-thatcreole-and-juunas).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use the following way to get the **easy auth** token easily.

1.Vist the following url from browser and input your creditial.

```
https://{yourfunctionAppName}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad
```

[image]

2.After that we could get the easy auth token after decode the url.

[image]

3.Test it with Postman

[image]

Comment: I am in a similar situation at the moment but I want to generate easy auth token from Postman too rather than generating it manually. Is there a way to get easy auth token through postman by making http calls just like we do from UI ?