# azure app authentication/authorization between apps

Tags: facebook, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-authentication

I have an azure mobile all that uses authentication/authorization with facebook, everything is setup and working on my mobile app, I’m able to authenticate with facebook and get an access token.

I also have a web app (ODATA) hosted in azure and also uses authentication/authorization with facebook and its also working fine if I try to access the ODATA service it redirects me to facebook to login.

According to this article (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/) I should be able to silently or programmatically send the access token from the mobile app to the web app by sending a json with acces_token key.

The may question is how I do this, is that access token in the header or where should I write it I can find any information from it. I would really appreciate a code example or an article that can guide me to accomplish my task

Comment: Just add this header to your request: `Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eX..` - grab the token from HTTP headers (coming from the browser) or by calling `/.auth/me` - more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765687/4148708

Comment: ok the answer make sense, I think my problem is that the user is not being created in active directory

Comment: here I created another question about how to create the user in azure ad after login with facebook https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926786/create-user-in-azure-active-directory-after-login-with-facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The may question is how I do this, is that access token in the header or where should I write it I can find any information from it. I would really appreciate a code example or an article that can guide me to accomplish my task.

Based on my understanding, you are using [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow) for independently contacting the facebook then retrieve the `access_token` from facebook, then you could leverage the `access_token` to login with your azure mobile app backend.

Also, you have a Azure Web App uses authentication/authorization with facebook and **use the same facebook App ID**. Then you want to leverage the `access_token` in your mobile client to access your another Azure Web App. At this point, you could login with your azure web app and retrieve the `authenticationToken` as follows:

```
POST https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook
Body {"access_token":"******"}
```

[image]

Then, you could leverage the `authenticationToken` and set it as the `x-zumo-auth` header when accessing your azure web app as follows:

```
Get https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/values
Header x-zumo-auth:{authenticationToken}
```

[image]

Additionally, you could create your custom Web API endpoints within your azure mobile app, details you could follow adrian hall's book about [Custom HTTP Endpoints](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter4/custom/).