# Developing Azure functions locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions, restful-authentication, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I am leading a large team of azure functions developers. So, most of the examples quoted by Microsoft using the azure web interface don't work for me. I am developing Azure functions locally using emulators to save some costs. I publish all my functions through visual studio into my integration environment.

I am developing a bunch of azure functions that need the api gateway to handle the authentication workflows using Azure AD B2C. Now, there's no api gateway emulator or an Azure AD B2C emulator that I can run locally. My authentication workflows involve intercepting requests to the api, redirecting them to AD B2C for authentication and the subsequent addition of the auth-token to the http header and then invoking the http-triggered azure functions.

Now, the question becomes, how do I test authentication workflows?
How can I setup the api gateway to register my functions running locally in visual studio as api endpoint for my api gateway in the cloud?

Comment: As of now, we do not have support to test authentication locally. Adding [Easy Auth](https://cgillum.tech/category/easy-auth/) support to function apps is being tracker [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/33). Adding support for local development with AAD credentials is part of roadmap but there is no ETA for this yet.

Comment: I am trying to build an open world internet platform which will scale. I don't want to build my own OAuth framework and interception mechanism for security . I want to use an API Gateway so I can throttle the API throughput. If the gateway could handle authentication so I don't have to setup a bunch of other integrations just for security everywhere. Azure bizspark credits run out very quickly when you start using services like the api gateway. I am struggling to find a good model to facilitate local development without twisting myself into a pretzel trying to get my developers productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did:

1. Added an "authorize" API that handles general-purpose authorization against foreign authorities.  This API returns my own JWT with my own custom claims that lasts for a some limited amount of time.
2. Changed all of my other API's to use my custom JWT.

Advantages:

- Super easy to test locally.   I just add #if DEBUG sections to the authorization API to skip normal authorization and give me a JWT of my design.
- I can put whatever I want in the claim, so I use it as a cache to reduce external authorization calls.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another alternative if you are developing a SPA that uses Azure-AD or Azure B2C via [Easy Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-functions%2Ftoc.json#-configure-with-express-settings), which will do your JWT token validation for you and leaving you to do the following:

Your SPA is going to get a token even locally so do the following:

1. Inject the [ClaimPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#working-with-client-identities) into your function
2. Check if the user is authenticated (e.g., principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) and return UnauthorizedResult if they are not.
3. Check for an issuer claim.  If the principal has one, it went through Express Auth., your JWT token was validated by it and you can get your claims from it immediately.
4. If there is no issuer, it's local development and you can turn to the header and pull the JWT token out yourself and get your claims.  You could also IFDEF this out for conditional build so that your doubly sure that it's local development.

Here is some example code of pulling the JWT token out of the header (HttpRequest is injected into each function):

```
private JwtSecurityToken ReadJwtTokenFromHeader(HttpRequest req)
{
   if (req.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
   {
       var authHeader = req.Headers["Authorization"];
       var headerValue = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);

       var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
       return handler.ReadJwtToken(headerValue.Parameter);
   }

   return null;
}
```

Note:  This requires the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt NuGet package to use JwtSecurityTokenHandler.

Comment: On my development env, i am getting IsAuthenticated as true but there are no AuthorizationHeader. How can i get this header?

Comment: @RohanKulkarni, your client should send 'Authorization: Bearer...' header

Answer (score 3):

Taking @David-Yates's answer I substituted Principal when running locally

```
module Debug = begin

    open System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
    open System.Net.Http.Headers
    open System.Security.Claims

    let setPrincipalFromBearerToken (log : ILogger) (req : HttpRequest) =
        log.LogInformation ("Reading Authorization header")
        let success, authHeader = req.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization")
        if not success
        then log.LogWarning ("Authorization header missing")
        else
        match Seq.tryExactlyOne authHeader with
        | None -> log.LogWarning ("Authorization header has 0 or more than 1 value")
        | Some headerValue ->
            let headerValue = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(headerValue);
            log.LogInformation ("Authorization header succesfully parsed")

            let handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            let token = handler.ReadJwtToken(headerValue.Parameter);
            log.LogInformation ("JWT succesfully parsed")
            let identity =
                ClaimsIdentity(
                    req.HttpContext.User.Identity,
                    token.Claims)//,
                    //Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme),
                    //"oid", "roles")
            let principal = ClaimsPrincipal(identity)
            req.HttpContext.User <- principal
            let userIdClaim =
                principal.Claims
                |> Seq.where (fun c -> c.Type = "oid") // TODO: Use const from MS package if possible
                |> Seq.head
            log.LogInformation ("Principal succesfully updated, user ID '{0}'", userIdClaim.Value)
end

let isLocal = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID"))
if isLocal then Debug.setPrincipalFromBearerToken log req
```

Comment: By the way, I tried to get `MSI_TOKEN` from the function on the Azure portal and put it into the `localsettings.json` file in .NET 5 function and now it perfectly authenticates to a KeyVault via Azure AD