# Azure Function ClaimsPrincipal locally

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm using Azure AD Authenticated Azure Function. Everything work fine when deployed on Azure.

```
    public static async Task<IActionResult> ExportT(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ClaimsPrincipal principal,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var c = principal.Claims.Select(x => x.Value);

        return new OkObjectResult(c);

    }
```

Return :

```
[ "38a1e83b-c1d3-4fd7-bdc6-ef2447", "https://sts.windows.net/635e38ef-108e-4a26-b718-bbd532/", "1564501257", "1564501257", "1564505157", "42FgYFCuNWnL3ROWG9x3p4EzN3+c/6u8Gh5jV7sT0A", "pwd", "test", "test", "92.169.93", "test", "36fbab-425b-9d65-b2425ef3d9bf", "a1c1ee35-67ab-4f3a-2877c5580b1e", "ES_SALARIED", "XboeusxsxyvnjhCT_vJHkzncPE2JBU58Q50", "635e38ef-26-b718-bbd960991532", "testdedev@ins.coop", "testdedev@ins.coop", "PJ0vEo70o0G__HrwX8ghAA", "1.0" ]
```

But when executing locally with VS2019 I get :

```
[ "Admin" ]
```

Any idea ?

Regards,

Comment: I assume in Azure you have secured your Function with Azure AD auth?! If so, this is obivously not in place when running locally.

Comment: Yes, you'r right but because i'm passing an authorization header i was hoping to be able to get my identity available in ClaimsPincipal :( Looks like it's not as simple (as explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587136/how-to-get-current-user-identity-in-azure-function-with-azure-authentication/48240085#48240085) I suppose I need to mock some identity object to use locally.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: Trying to use my ClaimPrincipal object the same way locally than deployed .... be able to retrieve the authentication the same way. (As my exemple do)

Comment: Maybe you can cross check your access policies to give admin the same rights as the Identity you app runs on in azure. This would give you the same result I believe.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could find to getting this to work was this using these examples from this [repo](https://github.com/maliksahil/AzureFunctionsAADDotNet) ([commit at the time of writing](https://github.com/maliksahil/AzureFunctionsAADDotNet/tree/9d37ac2928b34a19f1ca2c75279f0d6aa2bea0bc)).

In the example AuthenticationService I added `context.User = claimsPrincipal;` after validating the claim.

From there, I can do the following on my HTTP Triggers:

```
[Authorize]
[FunctionName("AuthTest")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AuthTest(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "test")] HttpRequest req)
{
    // Current user identity returned
    // (quickly thrown together as you get a circular reference error when converting to JSON):
    return new OkObjectResult(
       req.HttpContext.User.Identities.Select(x =>
          new {
                 Claims = x.Claims.Select(y => new
                    {
                        y.Type,
                        y.Value,
                        y.Issuer,
                        y.Properties
                    }),
                 x.Name,
                 x.Actor,
                 x.AuthenticationType,
                 x.NameClaimType
                })
            );
 }
```

---

### Coming in Cold?

Providing you have an access token, you can then do a `GET: http://localhost:7071/api/test` with a JWT token in your header.

E.g:

[image]

You will also need to

- [Register an
  app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-web-apis)
  with Azure AD
- Use the [MSAL client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal)
  on your front-end to get a token

## Caveats

This isn't using "easy auth". I opted for this approach as I wanted to use [MSAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) which supports AAD V2. I found AAD V2 isn't yet supported:

> At this time, AAD V2 (including MSAL) is not supported for Azure App Services and Azure Functions. Please check back for updates.
>   [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization)

I had a real fight getting this far. *Easy auth* doesn't seem like an option if you need to test your apps before pushing to production. Even after this answer, I have no idea how you can make authorization as simple as a [normal Web API policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-3.0) approach.